# Installer run as Admin is getting Access is Denied trying to kill a process from a Custom Action module

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action, access-denied

Installer run as Admin is getting Access is Denied trying to kill a process from a Custom Action module

The custom action is being handled via chef's Omnibus by a consumed Custom Action project.

I have other custom action methods inside the same module that are executing fine, but none this system-wide and invasive. What I don't understand is why I'm getting Access is Denied nor how to work around it when already as Admin.

I added `string userID = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and got this back from my debugging message:

> `The UserID returned from WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

When I added try/catch blocks to catch the exception message, it was just "Access is Denied." I isolated it down to the `Process.Kill()` line when it triggered.

> MSI (s) (10:64) [14:24:02:799]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=RestartExplorer,,)
>   MSI (s) (10:64) [14:24:02:801]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=RestartExplorer,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=RestartExplorer,)
>   MSI (s) (10:98) [14:24:02:803]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\windows\Installer\MSI194.tmp, Entrypoint: RestartExplorer
>   SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\windows\Installer\MSI194.tmp-\
>   SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
>   Calling custom action installer_custom_action!installer_custom_action.CustomActions.RestartExplorer
>   Installer Custom Action Exception triggered: Access is denied
>   CustomAction RestartExplorer returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>   Action ended 14:24:02: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace installer_custom_action
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult RestartExplorer(Session session)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0];
            process.Kill();
            Process.Start("explorer");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

In the actual WiX file, there is where I'm idenitifying the custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="RestartExplorer"
                      Execute="deferred"
                      BinaryKey="installer_custom_action.CA.dll"
                      DllEntry="RestartExplorer"
                      Impersonate="no"
                      Return="check" />
```

Then lower inside the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` area, I have this:

```
<Custom Action='RestartExplorer' 
        Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```